# How to display integer values on a window using silver light C# application

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, web-applications, silverlight-5.0

I am beginner to `c#` `silverlight-5` web application.I created project by choosing "silverlight 5" and "ASP.NET web application" while selecting the project in visual studio-2010.

I have to create a GUI which will display a window on Internet explorer that will contain the output exactly same as given below obtained on console application. I create GUI using toolbox which will have code in **xml** and then i handle their button clicks in **c#**.

Now What i have to do is to display the value of "symbol" and "freq"(both integer) variable inside a window in internet explorer. In console application i do so by writing following code:

```
public void Print_tree(Node tree) 
{
    Node pt = tree;
    while (pt != null) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Symbol : {0}  frequency is : {1}", pt.symbol, pt.freq);
        pt = pt.next;
    }
}
```

The output corresponding to it would be :

```
Symbol : 200 frequency : 20
Symbol : 195 frequency : 18
Symbol : 192 frequency : 14
Symbol : 188 frequency : 11
```

I want the same kind of display at Internet explorer window.
This console.WriteLine is used to print the value of "symbol" and "freq" which are integer value (Stored in a linked list "pt") at console but How to do that on window created at Internet explorer. Is it possible using **"TextBlock"** ? (Because i have to print in a manner like "Symbol : ValueOfSymbol  Frequency : ValueOfFrequency") (One is string and another is integer).

Please help me in doing it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly you can do;

```
<TextBlock>
   <Run Text="Symbol:"/>
   <Run Text="{Binding ValueOfSymbol}"/>
   <Run Text="Frequency:"/>
   <Run Text="{Binding ValueOfFrequency}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

would be one option, though I'm pretty sure there's also a Multi-Binding availability so you could form it that way as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks but i have done using other way. I prefer to work more in ".cs " file rather in ".xaml" file. so List box worked for me "listBox2.Items.Add("Symbol :" + pt.symbol + " -" + " Frequency : " + pt.freq);"

Answer (score 0):

I have done this using ListBox. Just a line and it worked :

```
  listBox2.Items.Add("Symbol :" + pt.symbol + " -" + " Frequency : " + pt.freq);
```

May be useful for any future user.